# Vanity URLS: mod_rewrite and SQL query return bad flag delimiters error

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, vanity-url

I'm using a very simple method to enable vanity URLS on my website and yet, i get **a 500 server error.**

I want to enable URLs like this : `mysite.com/ben` instead of `mysite.com/profile.php?id=2`

Here's the code i'm using in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f  
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]</pre>
```

Here's the query at the top of profile.php:

```
$getName = explode("/",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$result = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getName[3]'");  
if (count($result) == 0)
 {
    header ('Location:404.php'); 
 }
```

Now, with this script I get a 500 server error on any page I try to access.
In my Apache error log, I can see: **RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters**

What does this mean?

Comment: Check the apache error log to see what the issue is. By default the log writes to somewhere like `/var/logs/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I just checked, here's the error I get: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any stray spaces anywhere?

Comment: Do you really have `&gt;` in your .htaccess code?

Comment: @JonLin I've checked, it doesn't look like there's any

Comment: @anubhava Yes i do. Do you think that might cause the issue?

Comment: @BenRifff: What is actually the purpose of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} &gt;""`

Comment: It's supposed to be `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} >""` I gather, but that's not what the error log is complaining about

Comment: It might be, are you actually trying to match a file on the server with `>""` in the name?

Comment: Technically that is not a valid name. Try removing the first condition and rule and see if you get the same error?

Comment: @JonathanKuhn when I remove it, i get a different error: bad argument line '%{REQUEST_FILENAME}'. this piece of code was taken from a tutorial online. http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/   . i'm surprised it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is going to sound kind of dumb, but looking at the link that you posted here: http://culttt.com/2011/11/16/how-to-make-vanity-urls-using-php-htaccess-and-mysql/

The `</pre>` at the end of their example **will cause a 500 server error**. And, not surprisingly, when I look at my error logs, it says:

```
 /var/www/localhost/htdocs/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters
```

So remove the `</pre>` and change the `&gt;` to `>`.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said and I now get the following error: :  Undefined offset: 3 in line 7 which is `$result = query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getName[3]'");` Any ideas how to fix it ?

Comment: @BenRifff That's a PHP error. It's saying there's no index at "3" in `$getName[3]`.

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`

There is extra white space at the end of this line after the `-f` flag.

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace your .htaccess code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ profile.php?username=$1 [L,QSA]
```